# Remote Video Grid not Show in Agora VideoCall

Tags: flutter, agora

I have Implement Agora Video call in my project. In my Project My Video is shown but other user video grid not show . Sometimes its Appearing but sometimes not. How am Resolving this Problem Please give me some Suggestions i will highly Appricate your efforts

I wil also follow agora documentation :- [https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=flutter](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but still i dont know what i do wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Follow instructions and try to implement if Still facing issue check my git code.

1. For Agora Video call need dependency:- **agora_rtc_engine: ^5.3.1 or
   latest version**
2. Login and Create Project on - https://www.agora.io/en/
3. Follow instruction how to Implement Agora video call
   documentation-
   https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=flutter
4. I have created a demo of Videocall using Agora please check my
   github code https://github.com/SharmaJatin1997/VideoCall-Flutter

In this Demo we have to create full VideoCall